# Conditionally displaying template content inside ng-repeat

Tags: html, angularjs

I'm using ng-repeat to loop render an angular template potentially thousands of times, and wondering what is the most efficient way to go about conditionally altering it's display. For example, each item in the loop has a 'type', which has a corresponding icon. There are a few ways to go about this:

1. Purely css/html - this seems the most efficient angular-wise, but will mean a lot more html in the DOM

   ```
   <li class="{{item.type}}">
       <i class="type-1-icon"></i>
       <i class="type-2-icon"></i>
       <i class="type-3-icon"></i>
   </li>
   ```

And then in the css:

```
    li i { display:none; }
    li.type-1 i.type-1-icon { display:block; }
    li.type-2 i.type-2-icon { display:block; }
    li.type-3 i.type-3-icon { display:block; }
```

2. Using ng-if - tidies up the dom, but could be less efficient evaluating the ng-if for lots of records?

   ```
   <li>
       <i class="type-1-icon" ng-if="item.type == 'type-1'"></i>
       <i class="type-2-icon" ng-if="item.type == 'type-2'"></i>
       <i class="type-3-icon" ng-if="item.type == 'type-3'"></i>
   </li>
   ```
3. Using ng-switch

   ```
   <li ng-switch on="item.type">
       <i class="type-1-icon" ng-switch-when="type-1"></i>
       <i class="type-2-icon" ng-switch-when="type-2"></i>
       <i class="type-3-icon" ng-switch-when="type-3"></i>
   </li>
   ```
4. Using ng-show (same for ng-hide). Similar to #1 I'm guessing

   ```
   <li>
       <i class="type-1-icon" ng-show="item.type == 'type-1'"></i>
       <i class="type-2-icon" ng-show="item.type == 'type-2'"></i>
       <i class="type-3-icon" ng-show="item.type == 'type-3'"></i>
   </li>
   ```

Anyway, I realise that all 4 approaches will work fine, but I'd love to learn a bit more about which is best for a potentially large dataset and why. Thanks!

Comment: If you have a large dataset maybe consider infinite-scrolling \ pagination to limit the amount of data rendered? It would also help to know how frequently the condition for rendering changes client-side (is it something decided by the server or by the client?)

Comment: Yes will be using infinite scroll, but would still like to know best way to go about the conditionals. Not entirely sure how often items will be re-rendered - but the 'type' won't change often for a particular item once it's rendered

Comment: I'm not sure there's a best approach if you don't have many constraints. I would consider that ng-if actually removes the HTML from the DOM (if you don't pass the if) while ng-show simply makes it invisible. Is it a noticeable different for, say, 25 rows? I don't know. Very curious to see if more experienced devs have something to add.

Comment: Yeah I'm just getting started with angular so just want to make sure I'm doing things right (and I realise there may be more than one right way). My thinking with ng-if is that it has to evaluate the conditional client-side for every possible item-type, for every list item, meaning 1000 'evaluations' for 100 items if there are 10 possible types. This could be slower than just adding all the possible icons to the html & showing/hiding with a simple class name on the parent